# checkbox property using jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

i m a beginner.
i want that when a checkbox is checked then it should allow user to write something in a txtbox. initially the txtbox is disabled. what i should write inside the function using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" />
<label for="cb">label for checkbox</label>
<input type="text" id="txt" disabled="disabled" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var checkbox = $('#cb');
        var textfield = $('#txt');

        checkbox.click(function() {
            if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                textfield.removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else {
                textfield.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[working example with visibilty](http://jsfiddle.net/kNBdC/)
[working example with disabled-state](http://jsfiddle.net/kNBdC/1/)

additionally:
as you are working with asp.net, your assignments should look like, eg:

```
var checkbox = $('#<%= this.cb.ClientID %>');
```

you should be aware of the way how the server-controls get rendered either (to choose an appropriate selector).
furthermore: you should also be aware of the fact, that `disabled`-inputs won't get posted, whereas `readonly`-inputs are no problem to handle...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mycheckbox').click(function() 
{ 
   $("#mytextbox").attr('disabled','');
}
);
```

Comment: its early, extra {'s tend to sneak in ;)

Comment: ah, ok. *goes to fetch cup of coffee* ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    //To Disable the Check box on page Load
    $('#TextBox').attr('disabled', 'disabled');     

    //On Click of the Check Box 
    $('#CheckBoz').click(function() 
    {
        if($('#CheckBoz').is(':checked'))
        {
            $('#TextBox').removeAttr('disabled');            
        }
        else
        {           
            $('#TextBox').attr('disabled', 'disabled');            
        }    
    });
});
```

I Hope this code works perfectly for you and u jst need to paste it in your page and check the Component name according to it.